# append array stored a many ch to to a char array[]

Tags: c, arrays

from now I have a `ch[5]` stored `{'a','b','c','d','e'}`

I have another array char loadtext[i];
which will store many strings.;
like `loadtext[0] = "abced"`

how can append the five char together;
I have tried;

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
strcat(loadtext[0],ch[i];
}
```

but ir return erorrs

```
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You mean you need to make an array like {'abced','a','b','c','d','e'}

Comment: `{'a','b','c','d','e'}` is wrong, it should be `{'a','b','c','d','e', '\0'}`

Comment: @MichaelB. yup, that's is why @dbush ask me to add `\0` in end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strcat` function is used to copy strings.  You're not copying strings but individual characters, so just assign the values directly:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    loadtext[0][i] = ch[i];
}
loadtext[0][5] = '\0';
```

Note also that we add a null byte to the end of `loadtext[0]` to make the array of characters a string.

Comment: it is a must to add \0 to form a string?

Comment: @Antonymous Correct.  if there's no terminating null byte, it is not by definition a string.